# Ventura Installer ISO less than 2GB?

Tags: ventura

I am uploading an ISO to GitHub Releases which is around 11GB. But when I try to upload it, it says the max file size is 2GB. Is there any Ventura ISO with the maximum file size of 2GB?

Comment: No. The OS is considerably larger. Why do you want to host it on your repository?

Comment: It's just for my application to download and write to the USB Flash drive.

Comment: It might be easier just to host a URL to Apple's download, and the text of the `createinstallmedia` command.

Comment: my app is cross-platform, so using an ISO is an easier route. i can't use creatinstallmedia can't be run outside macOS.

Comment: There are no Ventura ISO's, so whether or not there is one no larger than 2gb is up to however you created the one you think you have.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub [recommends individual files are less than 50 MB](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github) and the whole repository of 1 GB or less.

For [releases the file size is limited](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/about-releases) to 2 GB.

They [block files greater than 100 MB](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-git-large-file-storage), releases greater than 2 GB and require Git Large File Storage or Dropbox for larger files.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was uploading to the GitHub releases section. I'm really sorry

Comment: Releases are limited to 2 GB. When you say Ventura iso, you are not referring to Apple’s operating system right? Just your application that runs on Ventura. 2 GB is a lot for a release. Unless you are copying an os install, you shouldn’t exceed the limit?

Comment: I am copying an OS Installation media but when I Create it, it says file bigger than 2 GB

Comment: + that installation media is in a `.iso` format

Comment: So don’t do that? Well, don’t do that I’m a GitHub release. It is not supported, officially blocked by them.

Comment: @RishonJR You almost certainly don't have a distribution license for macOS, so you can't upload it to **anywhere** and expect people to download it.

Comment: @RishonJR I guess I just assumed when you said “Ventura Installer” you were not talking about anything that you didn’t write. I asked to confirm you were not talking about Apple’s Operating System above. You didn’t respond. Please confirm you are not trying to upload Appe’s OS, because short of that it is amazing you have so much to distribute that you exceed 2G.

Comment: @Marc Wilson I have no intentions for other people to download it, it's just an ISO that my App will download and install. I'm not using the app directly because I want the macOS Installer to be written on any platform.

Comment: @James Risner I'm trying to upload apple's Mac installer so my app can download and write to a USB.(It is for an app that I'm writing [here.](https://github.com/RishonDev/WaveUSB-Beta) )

Comment: @RishonJR you do not have the right to upload it, unless you have a written contract with Apple to do so. Have you paid for and obtained that right?

Comment: Uhm No...  Should I pay them money to do so...

Comment: Why do you think you shouldn’t?

Comment: I Can't pay apple as I'm not even old enough to own a bank account... nor to get a proper job.

Comment: Well without paying, you are violating Apple copyright and attempting to use GitHub to do it. That also violates GitHub usage agreement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141174/discussion-between-rishon-jr-and-james-risner).